# Grouping while maintaining next record

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table (NerdsTable) with some of this data:

```
-------------+-----------+----------------
id             name          school
-------------+-----------+----------------
1              Joe         ODU
2              Mike        VCU
3              Ane         ODU
4              Trevor      VT
5              Cools       VCU
```

When I run the following query

```
SELECT id, name, LEAD(id) OVER (ORDER BY id) as next_id
    FROM dbo.NerdsTable where school = 'ODU';
```

I get these results:

```
[id=1,name=Joe,nextid=3] 
[id=3,name=Ane,nextid=NULL]
```

I want to write a query that does not need the static check for

```
where school  = 'odu'
```

but gives back the same results as above. In another words, I want to select all results in the database, and have them grouped correctly as if i went through individually and ran queries for:

```
SELECT id, name, LEAD(id) OVER (ORDER BY id) as next_id FROM dbo.NerdsTable where school = 'ODU';
SELECT id, name, LEAD(id) OVER (ORDER BY id) as next_id FROM dbo.NerdsTable where school = 'VCU';
SELECT id, name, LEAD(id) OVER (ORDER BY id) as next_id FROM dbo.NerdsTable where school = 'VT';
```

Here is the output I am hoping to see:

```
[id=1,name=Joe,nextid=3] 
[id=3,name=Ane,nextid=NULL]
[id=2,name=Mike,nextid=5] 
[id=5,name=Cools,nextid=NULL]
[id=4,name=Trevor,nextid=NULL]
```

Here is what I have tried, but am failing miserably:

```
SELECT id, name,
    LEAD(id) OVER (ORDER BY id) as next_id
    FROM dbo.NerdsTable
    ORDER BY school;

-- Problem, as this does not sort by the id. I need the lowest id first for the group

SELECT id, name,
    LEAD(id) OVER (ORDER BY id) as next_id
    FROM dbo.NerdsTable
    ORDER BY id, school;

-- Sorts by id, but the grouping is not correct, thus next_id is wrong
```

I then looked on the [Microsoft doc site](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173454.aspx) for aggregate functions, but do not see how i can use any to group my results correctly. I tried to use GROUPING_ID, as follows:

```
SELECT id, GROUPING_ID(name),
    LEAD(id) OVER (ORDER BY id) as next_id
    FROM dbo.NerdsTable
    group by school;
```

But I get an error:

```
is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause
```

Any idea as to what I am missing here?

Comment: `I want to write a query to be independent of the where clause above, but give me the same results when ODU becomes the school.`, what does this mean?. Can you show a desired result in that case so we can understand better?

Comment: We want to help but you have to be really clear what you are trying to do. You showed some sample data. After the query, what should that data look like?

Comment: I have tried to explain it better. Does this clear mud?

Comment: @angryip just put the desired output.

Comment: I have added desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your desired output it looks like you are just trying to order the records by school. You can do that like this:

```
SELECT id, name
FROM dbo.NerdsTable
ORDER BY school ASC, id ASC
```

I don't know what next ID is supposed to mean.

Comment: next id is the next record in the query result. && Your solution kinda gets me there, but i am sent back to my initial problem above, where the results start with the max id, as opposed to min. they are not sorted by the lowest number

Comment: I did that, and added this in between the select and from : LEAD(id) OVER (ORDER BY school, id ASC) as next_id and it worked. ty

Answer (score 0):

```
create table schools (id int, name varchar(50), school varchar(3))
insert into schools values (1, 'Joe', 'ODU'), (2, 'Mike', 'VCU'), (3, 'Ane',     
'ODU'), (4, 'Trevor', 'VT'), (5, 'Cools', 'VCU'), (6, 'Sarah', 'VCU')

select n.id, n.name, min(g.id) nextid
from schools n
left join
(
    select id, school
    from schools
) g on g.school = n.school and g.id > n.id
group by n.id, n.name

drop table schools
```